# Red line underneath tab name

Tags: java, android

Well, the images underneath say everything. I have absolutely no idea what causes the tab title to get underlined red. I guess it has something to do with the language (which is Dutch by the way). The tabs are generated with the help of SwipeyTabs and Fragments.

The code that adds the title to the tab is the following:

```
public TextView getTab() {
        TextView title = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, layout, false);
        title.setText(getStringFromCalendar(date));

        return title;
  }
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Example 1]
[image]

Comment: You might want to post some source of how you are populating the tab titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` to the tab TextView. I still have no idea why it was red in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tab name takes a CharSequence, you can pass it an UnderlineSpan which wraps a ForegroundColorSpan with the text you want.